# How to avoid destructuring mutation from Apollo useMutation hook?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, react-apollo

I am wrapping the `useMutation` hook from `react-apollo` so that I can send to `Sentry` the errors every time I use a mutation:

```
import { useMutation } from '@apollo/react-hooks'
import { DocumentNode } from 'graphql'
import { MutationHookOptions } from 'react-apollo'

type UseMutationWithSentryErrorsProps = {
  refetch: MutationHookOptions<any, Record<string, any>>
  from: string
  mutation: DocumentNode
}

export const useMutationWithSentryErrors = ({
  refetch,
  from,
  mutation
}: UseMutationWithSentryErrorsProps) => {
  const response = useMutation(mutation, refetch)

  const [_apolloMutation, { error: mutationError }] = response
  if (mutationError) {
    captureException(mutationError, {
      info: 'There was an error fetching data.',
      from
    })
  }

  return response
}
```

How I call the mutation is:

```
  const [updateSpeakerMutation] = useMutationWithSentryErrors({
    refetch,
    from: 'SomeProvider',
    mutation: UPDATE
  })
```

The problem is with this line:

```
  const [_apolloMutation, { error: mutationError }] = response
```

I get a `variable is not read` error. I can't access the response error without accessing the mutation, but I am not using the mutation in this wrapper function, but in the places where I truly use it. I tried the classic `_` syntax but still same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
const [, { error: mutationError }] = response
```

Note the comma

Comment: I opted to use it as an extra check `if (apolloMutation && mutationError) {etc.`